# forgot password is not sending message to my gmail account

Tags: php, email, gmail

Email is not sending to Gmail account `forgot_pass_identity` is set on the table. Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?
I check the code I did not find any mistake.

```
if(isset($_POST['forgotSubmit'])){
//check whether email is empty
    if(!empty($_POST['email'])){
    //check whether user exists in the database
    $prevCon['where'] = array('email'=>$_POST['email']);
    $prevCon['return_type'] = 'count';
    $prevUser = $user->getRows($prevCon);
    if($prevUser > 0){
        //generat unique string
        $uniqidStr = md5(uniqid(mt_rand()));;

        //update data with forgot pass code
        $conditions = array(
            'email' => $_POST['email']
        );
        $data = array(
            'forgot_pass_identity' => $uniqidStr
        );
        $update = $user->update($data, $conditions);

        if($update){
            $resetPassLink = 'http://example.com/resetPassword.php?fp_code='.$uniqidStr;

            //get user details
            $con['where'] = array('email'=>$_POST['email']);
            $con['return_type'] = 'single';
            $userDetails = $user->getRows($con);

            //send reset password email
            $to = $userDetails['email'];
            $subject = "Password Update Request";
            $mailContent = 'Dear '.$userDetails['first_name'].', 
            <br/>Recently a request was submitted to reset a password for your account. If this was a mistake, just ignore this email and nothing will happen.
            <br/>To reset your password, visit the following link: <a href="'.$resetPassLink.'">'.$resetPassLink.'</a>
            <br/><br/>Regards,
            <br/>mysite';
            //set content-type header for sending HTML email
            $headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8" ;
            //additional headers
            //send email
            mail($to,$subject,$mailContent,$headers);

            $sessData['status']['type'] = 'success';
            $sessData['status']['msg'] = 'Please check your e-mail, we have sent a password reset link to your registered email.';
        }else{
            $sessData['status']['type'] = 'error';
            $sessData['status']['msg'] = 'Some problem occurred, please try again.';
        }
    }else{
        $sessData['status']['type'] = 'error';
        $sessData['status']['msg'] = 'Given email is not associated with any account.'; 
    }

}else{
    $sessData['status']['type'] = 'error';
    $sessData['status']['msg'] = 'Enter email to create a new password for your account.'; 
}
//store reset password status into the session
$_SESSION['sessData'] = $sessData;
//redirect to the forgot pasword page
header("Location:forgotPassword.php");
}
```

Please help me how to resolve this issue. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: You might be sending the mail, and Gmail could be receiving it, but then it trashes it as spam. Your mail probably doesn't have a SPF record or DKIM. See: https://support.google.com/mail/answer/6227174?hl=en&ref_topic=6259779

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding following headers first.

```
$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8" . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'From: '.$from. "\r\n"; // Valid from address
```

Sending mail not only is linked to code, but actually depends on other parameters as well.

Do refer below links if this does not work.

[PHP mail function doesn't complete sending of e-mail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24644436/php-mail-function-doesnt-complete-sending-of-e-mail)

http://form.guide/email-form/php-script-not-sending-email.html

Hope this helps !

Comment: Thanks for marking this answer correct. Happy to help.